# How to fix button at bottom in android studio with scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

When scroll view scrolls I want the button to remain at the bottom like shown in the image. The place order button stays(It is a popup or not). Please help I am new at android. Thanks in advance

[image]

Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to use ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout as a parent layout and put the Place Order button and ScrollView inside it. ScrollView should fill the hole screen and Place Order stick to right and bottom of ConstraintLayout.

Comment: `How to fix button at bottom in android studio with scrollview` - How do you expect us to help in your code without your code?

Comment: Is this your complete layout?

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relMainUnspentTwo">

  </ScrollView>
  
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnContinueUnSpentTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/conti"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That button should not be part of the ScrollView then. What you need is to put the button in the parent layout, at the same level of your ScrollView. You can use either ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout.

It would look something like this if you use RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        ...
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true
        ... />
<RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, The button is also moving down with the scrollview I want the button to stay at the bottom whatever the height of the scrollview.  Please clear

Comment: @RahulChoudhary That's why you have to do what I mentioned. The button moves along with the scrollview because you probably have the button within your scrollview. Instead, you should put the button at the same level of your ScrollView, both within a parent layout such a RelativeLayout. Then just place the button at the bottom/end and it will not be affected by the scroll, it will stay always at that postiion.

Comment: That should work, is that what you tried? Can you share what's the actual result you seeing?

Comment: The button is not at the bottom it is actually below the recycler view. Whenever recycler view has height more than the screen's height button is not appearing(means it is appearing when we scroll till the end). Thank you

Comment: A screenshot would help to understand that better, but if I were you, I would try 2 things: 1. The Relative Layout should be math_parent for height, and 2. get rid of that orientation since that is specifically for LinearLayouts. Make those changes and attach an screenshot of what does it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:layout_above="@+id/search"` to your **recyclerView**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/search"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```